# Dragging divs beetween elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a table grid(10x10), and images in some of it's cells. I wanna the images to be draggable beetween the cells of grid(it'd be great if i could easily get the new position(x,y) of image). I'm using newest JQuery.

Comment: Is the table a must, or dragging without the table ok as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI [`.draggable()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Draggable) and [`.droppable()`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Droppable) will handle this nicely.

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GfPWV/) that illustrates one way to drag an image among table cells, and get the resulting cell coordinates within the table.

The general idea is to designate your draggable (the image, perhaps):

```
$('#yourimage').draggable();
```

Then set your table cells as droppables:

```
$('#tbl td').droppable({
  hoverClass: 'over', // highlight cells as you drag over them
  drop: function( e, ui ){
    /* get drop cell coordinates (1-indexed) */
    var row = cell.closest('tr').prevAll().length + 1;
    var col = cell.closest('td').prevAll().length + 1;        
    otherStuff();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use some sort of Drag and drop here.  If you don't want to roll your own, use the jQuery UI extension for drag and drop.  Check it out here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

Comment: But is there any automatic solution, to find out if my element is over td(and which one), or do i have to roll it on my own?

Comment: Its not built into HTML or JS.  If you want to drag-and-drop, you'll need to add that functionality to the page.  Since you're already using jQuery, jQuery UI should be straight forward.  You would simply apply a jQuery (UI) method to the contents of the cells, and provide some information about where they can be dropped.  Its pretty straight-forward.